# Compatibility of Eigenvalue-Eigenvector Identity with Cauchy Interlacing Inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the recent paper by Tao concerning the famous [eigenvalue-eigenvector identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) (pg-4), it is mentioned under point named **(vi) Compatibility with interlacing** that Eigenvalue-Eigenvector identity is compatible with Cauchy Interlacing Inequalities because each component of eigenvector has magnitude at most $1$.

It is clear that each eigenvector component has magnitude at most $1$ because eigenvector is assumed to be a unit vector. But how this makes it compatible with the Cauchy Interlacing Inequalities?

Further, What is meant by Compatibility here?

---

(Cauchy interlacing inequalities)
$$
\lambda_{i}(A) \leq \lambda_{i}\left(M_{j}\right) \leq \lambda_{i+1}(A) \tag{1}
$$

(Eigenvector-eigenvalue identity).
$$
\left|v_{i, j}\right|^{2} \prod_{k=1 ; k \neq i}^{n}\left(\lambda_{i}(A)-\lambda_{k}(A)\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\lambda_{i}(A)-\lambda_{k}\left(M_{j}\right)\right) \tag{2}
$$